# how to encrypt images in a for loop with python

Tags: python, encryption

I'm having an issue getting my for loop to encrypt all the images in my folder.
It seems that the `'x'` variable is causing an issue and won't`'bytearray'`. The glob is meant to loop through all the png files in my folder.

```
import glob
import os

for file in glob.glob("*.png"):
    x = bytearray(file)
    key = 100

    for index, value in enumerate(x):
        x[index] = value ^ key

    g = open("enc.png", "wb")
    g.write(x)
    g.close
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

glob.glob("*.png") lists the path of all the .png files present, thus what you are doing now is that you are getting the bytearray of the path of the .png files in x. You should use

```
f = open(file, "rb").read()
x = bytearray(f)
```

to get the bytearray of the file and then do your stuff.